# Webpack: Automatic publicPath is not supported in this browser

Tags: webpack

I have tried to start my webpack build and I got this error as below:

> if (!scriptUrl) throw new Error("Automatic publicPath is not supported in this browser").... Webpack version was v5-3-0.

I second time meet Webpack and I got confused. My previous webpack.config.js was the same, but Webpack version was v4-44-2.

Answer (score 6):

I suppose you use webpack for build server app
If it true then you need add this property in webpack config

```
 target: 'node',
```

Answer (score -4):

I would suggest just revert back to **Webpack version 4(v4) from version 5(v5)** & the error will be gone. Version 5 for the time being is difficult to manage & has lot of problems with it.